# Bad interpolation with texture in mesh

Tags: textures, uv-mapping

My mesh looks fine on Blender, but when I export it to my rendering engine (Ogre) the colors seem interpolated, screenshot below.

I am using `filtering none` in my material, so it shouldn't have any kind of interpolation. The rest of my meshes are fine, without any kind of weird effects.

Does anyone know what would be the cause of this? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: How is your mesh made, is it a black and white texture? What size is the texture in pixels? Does it help if you make it power-of-two size?

Comment: @KromStern I think it was a mipmapping problem, solved it by using 0 mipmaps (which should have done in the first place by using `filtering none`, which is weird)

Comment: IIRC filtering tells how to interpolate between neighbor texels, but it does not controls which mipmap to pick. Which is still strange, because your blurred pic has exactly the same texel count (mipmap 0)

Comment: @KromStern I know, meant to say that it should have been solved by using no filtering.